# Suggestions for python assert function

Tags: python, assert

I'm using assert multiple times throughout multiple scripts, I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on a better way to achieve this instead of the functions I have created below.

```
def assert_validation(expected, actual, type='', message=''):
    if type == '==':
        assert expected == actual, 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '!=':
        assert expected != actual, 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '<=':
        assert expected <= actual, 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '>=':
        assert expected >= actual, 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)

def assert_str_validation(expected, actual, type='', message=''):
    if type == '==':
        assert str(expected) == str(actual), 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '!=':
        assert str(expected) != str(actual), 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '<=':
        assert str(expected) <= str(actual), 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
    elif type == '>=':
        assert str(expected) >= str(actual), 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' %(expected, actual, message)
```

Comment: Seriously though, can you explain the context?  I'm confused as to why you have cases for `<=` and `>=` as well as `!=`.

Comment: What's wrong with the assert statement?

Comment: Did your browser do that when you pasted, or do you really double-space your code?

Comment: the browser did this, next time i'll clean it up.

Answer (score 11):

Well this is certainly shorter... can you really not just use `assert expected == actual` or whatever in the scripts themselves?

```
def assert_validation(expected, actual, type='', message='', trans=(lambda x: x)):
    m = { '==': (lambda e, a: e == a),
          '!=': (lambda e, a: e != a),
          '<=': (lambda e, a: e <= a),
          '>=': (lambda e, a: e >= a), }
    assert m[type](trans(expected), trans(actual)), 'Expected: %s, Actual: %s, %s' % (expected, actual, message)

def assert_str_validation(expected, actual, type='', message=''):
    assert_validation(expected, actual, type, message, trans=str)
```

Comment: Should be +1 for the first sentence. +1 for actually solving the problem and +1 for minimizing the performance hit. Unfortuneatly I can upvote it only once :)

Comment: assert_str_validation should be assert_validation(str(expected), str(actual), ...) and the str parameter is unused and can be removed.

Comment: In fact it should be `assert m[type](str(expected), str(actual))...`, and str in `assert_validation` could be better named, but that's just nitpicking.

Comment: Yep, fixed both of those.  str was renamed to trans (for transform) and is now actually used.

Comment: I minor refinement to an incredibly concise solution would be to make the default `type` argument `'=='` rather than `''`.

Comment: ... and `actual=True` default argument would further simplify some of the calls to this function and make it behave a bit more like `assert`