# Passing expressions to functions

Tags: python, function, arguments, operators

In SQLAlchemy, it appears I'm supposed to pass an expression to [`filter()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html#common-filter-operators) in certain cases. When I try to implement something like this myself, I end up with:

```
>>> def someFunc(value):
...     print(value)

>>> someFunc(5 == 5)
True
```

**How do I get the values passed to `==` from inside the function?**

I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
 >>> def magic(left, op, right):
 ...    print(left + " " + op + " " + right)

 >>> magic(5 == 5)
 5 == 5
```

What about if one of the parameters was an object?

Comment: Follow up question about the ORMs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185537

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can achieve your example if you make "op" a function:

```
>>> def magic(left, op, right):
...     return op(left, right)
...
>>> magic(5, (lambda a, b: a == b), 5)
True
>>> magic(5, (lambda a, b: a == b), 4)
False
```

This is more Pythonic than passing a string. It's how functions like [`sort()`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) work.

Those SQLAlchemy examples with `filter()` are puzzling. I don't know the internals about SQLAlchemy, but I'm guessing in an example like `query.filter(User.name == 'ed')` what's going on is that `User.name` is a SQLAlchemy-specific type, with an odd implementation of the `__eq()` function that generates SQL for the `filter()` function instead of doing a comparison. Ie: they've made special classes that let you type Python expressions that emit SQL code. It's an unusual technique, one I'd avoid unless building something that's bridging two languages like an ORM.

Comment: Note that there's no need to parenthesize lambda.

Comment: True, but putting it in parenthesis makes it easier to read in this case due to the internal parameters of the lambda.

Comment: If you like--it's just superfluous parens to me.

Comment: the storm ORM also overloads the == operator

Answer (score 10):

An even more pythonic variant of Nelson's solution is to use the operator functions from the [operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module in the standard library; there is no need to create your own lambdas.

```
>>> from operator import eq
>>> def magic(left, op, right):
...   return op(left, right)
... 
>>> magic(5, eq, 5)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The expression `5 == 5` is evaluated and only then is the result passed to someFunc. The function just gets `True` (the `True` object, to be precise), no matter what the expression was.

Edit: Concerning your edit, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179096/suggestions-for-python-assert-function) is kind of close.

Edit 2: You could just pass the expression as a string and use eval, like this:

```
>>> def someFunc(expression_string):
...    print(expression_string, "evaluates to", eval(expression_string))

>>> someFunc("5 == 5")
5 == 5 evaluates to True
```

Don't know whether that helps you. Keep in mind that `eval` is a powerful tool, so it's dangerous to pass arbitrary (and possibly even user-generated) input to it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement `__eq__()` . For example ::

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self, '==', other)
```

Then, for the function, which you want to get the expression, like ::

```
def my_func(expr):
    # deal with the expression
    print(expr)

>>> a = A()
>>> my_func(a == 1)
(<__main__.A object at 0x1015eb978>, '==', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can return tuples from **eq**:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
            return (self.value, other.value)


f1 = Foo(5)
f2 = Foo(10)
print(f1 == f2)
```

Comment: You can return anything you want from `__eq__`, but returning something that can't be coerced to a bool to compare equality--the purpose of `__eq__`--is a really bad idea.

Comment: It's probably bad practice, but this is a theoretical question anyway. More of a "How is this possible?" type thing.

Comment: SQLalchemy really does something like this?  That's one library I won't be touching with a 20-foot steel pole.  It's a gross, disgusting hack.  (Not attacking you--you're just explaining how they might have done it.)

Comment: It is pretty strange. I wonder why they didn't use something like User.name.isEqualToInTheContextOfFilter("ed")

Comment: Sqlalchmey, sqlobject and pyparsing, both overeride pretty much every operator when dealing with their internal objects.  I personally think it makes the user declarations nicer but I understand the disgust.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. The result of the expression evaluation is passed to the function rather than the expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `__eq__` function to achieve this, and as for SQLAlchemy, they might be doing something like this

```
class Column(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("Perform and return custom logic here")
        return self.value == other

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value


class Model:
    id = Column()
    name = Column()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for attr in kwargs.items():
            if getattr(self, attr[0]):
                setattr(self, attr[0], attr[1])

test = Model(id=10, name="test")

print(test.id == 10)
print(test.name)
```