# What advantage is there to overriding the == operator in an ORM?

Tags: orm, operator-overloading

Apparently, a lot of ORMs do something like this:

```
query.filter(username == "bob")
```

to generate SQL like

```
... WHERE username = 'bob'
```

Why override the **==** operator instead of something like:

```
query.filter(username.eq("bob"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a subjective question, but in general I would say that the syntax for the former is more intuitive, and since many (if not most) ORM's do this it's generally expected (making it more intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of orm is brideing the "impedance mismatch" between object and relational world , So in theory you can be blissfully unaware of "=" in sql world and work with "==" of the object world.