# Can i use an equation as a parameter in python

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I am making a graph creating program in python and need to pass an equation as a parameter in a function (as needed to create a graph) and in that equation I need some variables that change while the function runs.

Thanks for helping its mutch appreciated.

I have tried to find solutions but I ain't that good so I haven't understand and what som explanation if you can.

```py
#inside a class and this is also simplified.
def function(self, e):
    x = 0
    for i in range(100):
        print(e)
        x += 1

classObj.function(x * 2)
```

I expect you to be able to add the x variable in the e parameter so i can make it more flexible but that variable is created functions for loop.

Comment: `x * 2` is not an equation; it's an expression. That expression is evaluated *before* `function` is actually called; `e` is the *result* of that evaluation.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea how to use one function but with different expressions in it. If you know im glad you answered.

Comment: With my limited knowledge, would it be acceptable to do `def function(self, x, operator, e)` Then you could define x, e, and even an operator such as * or +.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument expressions are evaluated *before* calling the function.

If you want to pass something dynamic, use a callback function. If the function is simple it can be written as a lambda.

```
def function(self, f):
    for i in range(100):
        print(f(i))

classObj.function(lambda x: x * 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but in Python you can pass a function as a parameter. To describe it we say that function are first-class citizens or that a language supports higher order functions.

Here's example of how you can achieve it:

```py
class YourClass:
    def function(self, e):
        x = 0
        for i in range(100):
            result = e(x)  # you can call a function passed as a parameter
            print(result)  # do something with a result
            x += 1


def multiply_by_2(x):
    return x * 2


def add_2(x):
    return x + 2


obj = YourClass()
obj.function(multiply_by_2)  # just use function name without parenthesis
obj.function(add_2)  # you can also pass different function!
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't defined `x`, you will get an error thrown when you call `classObj.function()`. You could pass the equation in as a string and call `exec()` or `eval()` on it.

For example:

```
def function(self, e):
    x = 0
    for i in range(100):
        print(exec(e))
        print(eval(e))# does same thing as above line
        x += 1

classObj.function("x * 2")
```

The difference between `eval()` and `exec()` is that `eval()` only *eval*uates one expression, but `exec()` can run large chunks of code. I recommend using the only what is necessary, so `exec()` would be overkill.

Maybe see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185199/passing-expressions-to-functions) on passing expressions to functions, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.