# How to make python method accept an expression as sqlalchemy does

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy's op could accept an expression and then evaluate it in the logic of the method,

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
sa.and_(table.col > 3)
```

How could this magic happend? I check the sqlalchemy's source code but not a clue.

Comment: I also found this thread which answer is `this magic could not happen`?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185199/passing-expressions-to-functions/1185254

Comment: For the above code, you are running the function `table.col.__gt__(3)`, which returns an expression class instance. You are then passing the instance into `and_()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and figured it out as the magic happend on table.col instance, which is initialed by a class which redefiend operations like '==', '>'